# Including SOIL library with find_package

Tags: c++, make, opengl, cmake

I have been porting my old OpenGL application to Ubuntu and stumbled across this problem. I can't figure out how to properly import SOIL library. I use CMake and I'd like to use the standard find_package routine for this so that potential users wouldn't have to build the library on their system manually.

Here's my CmakeLists (I simplified it a bit):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(MyProjectName)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++14")

set(SOURCE_FILES my source files)

# OpenGL
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
find_package(glfw3 REQUIRED)
find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)
find_package(SOIL REQUIRED)

add_executable(MyProjectName ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(MyProjectName glfw GLEW SOIL OpenGL)
```

The package can't be found and I get the message: `By not providing "FindSOIL.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "SOIL", but CMake did not find one.`

Apart from SOIL, everything works fine. And I've just reinstalled SOIL with `sudo apt-get install libsoil-dev` just in case.

You guys have any ideas why this doesn't work?

Comment: I really know next to nothing about cmake, however for `find_package` to work you would need a valid `FindSOIL.cmake` file - which I don't think is provided natively on Ubuntu even with the `extra-cmake-modules` package. There are a few home brewed ones around on the web but I can't vouch for any of them. Alternatively, you can locate the library manually and specify the full path explicitly in `target_link_libraries` as in this (non-answer answer) [CMake and SOIL linking](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53363442/4440445)